# Hair randomly disappeared partially from the top of my character's head

Tags: particles, hair, vertex-groups

I've been working on this character for a few weeks now. I had the hair all set up and working great. But for whatever reason the hair on the top of his head disappeared and I can't get it back. To make this weirder, I was editing a completely separate part of the model (the armor) when it happened. Resetting the edit of the hair doesn't work, and it looks completely fine in the particle edit mode. I also checked the vertex group and that looks the same as well. It does look like the hair is still there when I zoom out really far, but I'm not sure if its the same length and style.

[image: Bald!!]
[image: Far Away]
[image: Particle Edit Mode]
[image: How it used to look]

On further inspection it seems as though the hair is there, but it is below the scalp/ I have no idea how to fix this.
[image: WTF]

Comment: Welcome to SE. Check normals of faces. If some face have inverted normals then hairs will be inside scalp.

Comment: Good suggestion but I did already check that. They are correct.